# removing and updating eclipse

Tags: 14.04, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded eclipse Kepler but when I try to remove eclipse luna from opt by using command 
rm eclipse it gives me this message
rm:can't remove "eclipse":is a directory
what i'm trying to di is remove eclipse luna to install eclipse kepler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have installed it manually and not using `apt`
you have to use `-r` option with `rm`,
use `rm -r /opt/eclipse/`

But you have installed it using `apt` then use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

Comment: [rm:cannt remove '/Home/nasser/.eclipse/':no such file or directory]
when i type 
[sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
rm -r ~/.eclipse/]

Comment: @Nasser you have to do only one method. either `rm -r /opt/eclipse` or `sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse`. if you are getting `no such file or directory` just ignore it

Comment: Oh, thanks man for your straightforward instructions!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, and pressing the super key, then typing 'eclipse' and right clicking it gave me an option to delete it.